# Count number of non zero columns in a given set of columns of a data frame - pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df as shown below

df:

```
Id   Jan20  Feb20  Mar20  Apr20  May20  Jun20  Jul20  Aug20  Sep20  Oct20  Nov20  Dec20  Amount
1    20     0      0      12     1      3      1      0      0      2      2      0      100
2    0      0      2      1      0      2      0      0      1      0      0      0      500
3    1      2      1      2      3      1      1      2      2      3      1      1      300
```

From the above I would like to calculate `Activeness` value which is the number of non zero columns  in the month columns as given below.

```
'Jan20', 'Feb20', 'Mar20', 'Apr20', 'May20', 'Jun20', 'Jul20',
       'Aug20', 'Sep20', 'Oct20', 'Nov20', 'Dec20'
```

Expected Output:

```
  Id   Jan20  Feb20  Mar20  Apr20  May20  Jun20  Jul20  Aug20  Sep20  Oct20  Nov20  Dec20  Amount  Activeness
    1    20     0      0      12     1      3      1      0      0      2      2      0      100    7
    2    0      0      2      1      0      2      0      0      1      0      0      0      500    4
    3    1      2      1      2      3      1      1      2      2      3      1      1      300    12
```

I tried below code:

```
df['Activeness'] = pd.Series(index=df.index, data=np.count_nonzero(df[['Jan20', 'Feb20', 
        'Mar20', 'Apr20', 'May20', 'Jun20', 'Jul20',
       'Aug20', 'Sep20', 'Oct20', 'Nov20', 'Dec20']], axis=1))
```

which is working well, but I would like to know is there any method that is faster than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['Activeness'] = df.filter(like = '20').ne(0, axis =1).sum(1)
```